# How to animate the height and width using transforms?

Tags: css, reactjs, transform

there I am trying to build a search bar in which if you hover over the search icon it should expand. But animating the width directly is not performant, so I decided to use transforms but it is not scaling the search bar properly.
Here are the screenshots.

when using normal width
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JIIQevSx4riLsU8XagVtAMKeg1Bm3xf/view?usp=sharing)

When using transform
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TdqPB5z2ARrH0aYedKNiKpYtLLn6AmbD/view?usp=sharing)

CSS code:

```
.searchBox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.search-content {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.search-input {
  width: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.searchBox:hover > .search-input {
  /* width: 8rem; */
  transition: scaleX(8rem);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem; 
  background-color: rgb(240, 245, 248);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.25rem 0.25rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.searchSvg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.62rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

Here is the link of [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-feather-fbpf3?file=/src/components/Nav.css)

Comment: Transforming the element isn’t going to move the elements around it so it’s not enough to achieve what you want. As this isn’t a continuous animation but something that will happen rarely do you have to worry about performance?

Answer (score 1):

`transform: scaleX(8rem)` will not work, you should change it to a plain number without any unit.

Also, I don't think you should use `transform: scale()` on an `input` as it would make the text stretched out.

[image]

In this case, using the `width` property for the hover effect is not really affect the overall performance I think.

Answer (score 1):

try this, works fine (just add to below of your css codes):

```
.search-input {
  transition: width 1s;
}
 
.search-input:hover,.searchBox:hover .search-input{
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I was wanting these animations with the help of transforms as they would be performant on lower end devices.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Comment: but you need transition or animate anyway